# Merge multiple crossvalidations (same tasks, same learners)

Tags: mlr

I have several already calculated multiple benchmark results (10fold CV each) in which the same learners were applied to the same tasks. I would like to merge these in the sense of a 5-fold repeated 10fold CV and then analyze the resulting average performances. At first I thought I could use mergeBenchmarkResults, but this mlr-own function does not accept identical learner-task combinations. Can you think of another, convenient method to average my CVs? I would like to avoid a recalculation with a RepCV resampling strategy because of the long calculation time.

Best regards and thanks a lot,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

Use `mergeBenchmarkResults()` with different ID's for the same learner-task combinations. These IDs need to be created during creation of the learners, i.e. the learner IDs.

Comment: Am I right in saying that with your suggestion I would no longer be able to create a BenchmarkBoxplot in which the same task-learner combinations are displayed as one box, since they have different IDs (for example randomForest1, randomForest2...)? Also, following your suggestion, I would have to redo the cross-validations (which would take a lot of time), right?

Comment: Both correct. And I'd say having different boxplots would be the correct way to do it since you have different optimizations in these runs which should not be represented in one boxplot.